# How to sort collection of CMS blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, static-block, cms-block

Is there a way to sort a collection of cms blocks? I need to sort blocks by `identifier`. I tried to do it similar to a collection of products:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'DESC')
    ->load();
```

but it will not work because there is no `addAttributeToSort` method in the block collection object:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSort('identifier', 'DESC')
    ->load();
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

**addAttributeToSort**  use for **Eav  type Model**  *Catalog,Product,customer*. For *`Flat structure Model collection is not working`* except Sales model.
Also working on Sales Models

**CMS module's** Models are *use Flat structure*,So you don't `use the addAttributeToSort` .

You Should use `setOrder('[FieldName]','[ORDER]')` function.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
    ->getCollection()
    ->load();
$collection->setOrder('identifier', 'DESC');
```

Comment: Should I use `->setOrder` on the collection after I call `->load()` or before?

Answer (score 0):

After all those months I still meeting some problems ;)
Again, trying to sort something but Magento is like a stubborn donkey, whatever I do it won't do what I want

```
        $ar_blockIds = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_slide',true)
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',true)
        ->addFieldToFilter('start_time', array('lteq' => $now))
        ->addFieldToFilter('end_time', array('gteq' => $now))
        ->getAllIds()
    ;
```

How to sort ids by position ?
There is a field in table where position is stored but collection won't sort it ....
What am I doing wrong ?